# GNS3: Increase default NVRAM size

Tags: wifi-configuration

Which setting increases the default NVRAM size for a router node type in GNS 0.7.4 on GNU/Linux?

For example, a new *Router c3700* has a *NVRAM Size* of 55 KB. But I want every new router to have at least 75 KB. How is that configuration done?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a solution to this problem. Instead I found a workaround where I configure the c3700 with PCMCIA disk 1 (4MB). That provides the router with slot0. Then the following command copies the running config to a file on slot0:

```
copy running-config slot0:myconfig
```

Unfortunately the config is not picked up at boot so that the following command must be run manually every time.

```
copy slot0:myconfig running-config
```

Admittedly a very poor workaround